# JPA does not honours caching while creating entity manager factory dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, apache-tomee

I am using hibernate 4.2 and working on J2ee6 with tomee 1.7.4 . I need to write multi-tenant code, which can connect to various databases on demand. I tried doing this by creating multiple persistence units in persistence.xml, but during server startup tomee tries to validate connection to all persistence units(all of them might not be available during testing).

I tried to find some setting that tells tomee to skip validation of the connections at startup, but couldn't find one. So instead of creating entitymanager from persistence unit, I started using the function

```
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties)
```

and my persistence xml did not had any properties. This helped me solve this problem, but my caching stopped working when i moved to this model, it was working previously.

Can any one suggest some way in which i can ask tomee to skip validating persistence units at startup, or i can enable caching in the other way that i found.

My previous persistence.xml looked like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="localDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxxx?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxxx" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxxx" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="40"/>
        <!-- it must be set to LESS than the wait_timout setting for the mysql server (this setting defaults to 28800 secs (8 hours)) -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="28680" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces " value="true"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces " value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.mc.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.operationTimeout" value = "40000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.connectionFactory" value = "KetamaConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.hashAlgorithm" value = "HashAlgorithm.FNV1_64_HASH"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.servers" value = "xxxxx:xxxx"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="production" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxxx:3306/thewalkindb?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxxx" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="15"/>
        <!-- it must be set to LESS than the wait_timout setting for the mysql server (this setting defaults to 28800 secs (8 hours)) -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="28680" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces " value="true"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces " value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.mc.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.operationTimeout" value = "40000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.connectionFactory" value = "KetamaConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.hashAlgorithm" value = "HashAlgorithm.FNV1_64_HASH"/>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.servers" value = "xxxxxxxx"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

this works with caching , but it doesnot gives me flexibility to skip validation at tomee startup

My new persistence xml which does not honours caching, but allows me the flexibility is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="localDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties></properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="production" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am populating all the properties in a map and calling the function 
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties), but somehow it does not honours caching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the link between validation and caching. If you do a facade to the entity manager tenant aware you just have caching per entity manager which means you will not check local cache for production persistence unit.

If you want a single entity manager - =you'll get a single JPA cache in this mode which will merge local and production - you can use dynamic routing: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/dynamic-datasource-routing/README.html instead of dynamic persistence units.

Comment: My persistence.xml has 3 persistence units, with three different jdbc urls, during my development, i can't connect to prod, and during prod, i can't connect to dev server. Currently all the urls are defined in persistence xml, but i use only the relevant persistence unit in code. Tomee during the startup tries to connect to all persistence units, due to which every time, i have to change persistence xml. My main goal is to have same persistence xml, but tomee shouldn't connect to each by default

Comment: in conf/system.properties you can set:

PERSISTENCEUNIT.theUnitName.thePropertyName=thePropertyValue